# Why can't I shift 0xff0000 to 0xff000000 using << 2?

Tags: javascript, bit-shift

isn't this literally just moving the FF two bits to the left? for some reason, doing this in javascript I get 0x3fc0000

What I am trying to do is combine a hex color with an alpha channel mask

i.e. alpha = 0xff / full opacity

color = 0x00ff00

end result = 0xff00ff00

Answer (score 1):

`f` is 4 bits (`1111` in binary).  Two hexadecimal digits (`0xff`) is 8 bits.  So you need to shift by 8 to move over two hexadecimal places.

Comment: doing this i get -1000000

is this some js limitation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move it more than two bits 2 bits. If you want to shift these you need to use

```
color << 8;
```

Try the following in js fiddle

```
var color = 0x00ff00;
alert(color.toString(16));
color = color << 8;
alert(color.toString(16));
color = color | 0xff;
alert(color.toString(16));
console.log(color);
```